# How often should I back up my wallet if I use Bitcoin-Qt client?

Tags: bitcoin-core, backup

I am new to bitcoin and the first client I installed was Bitcoin-Qt (Bitcoin Core v0.9.3.0-gcea5e49-beta).

After installing and downloading the blockchain I immediately created a backup file. The other day I got my first bitcoins. Should I create a new backup file every time my wallet is updated (get more coins/spend coins) or its unnecessary (my first backup file contains all info needed for recovering all transaction history for my private key)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use default settings you have to backup your wallet.dat after you unlock each 100 your addresses. You also must backup your wallet.dat after you set a passphase on it. Do not create backups by copying your file while your client is running. Eigher create backup with a client menu or shutdown client and copy file to a different folder.